# Mathematics behind particle on a ring in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, boundary-conditions

In QM particle on a ring, the Schrodinger in cylindrical coordinates is given by $$\frac{d^2\psi}{d\phi^2}=\frac{-2IE}{\hbar^2}\psi$$
where $I$ is the moment of inertia.

Setting $ k^2=2IE/\hbar^2$, the solution is supposed to be $\psi_k(\phi)=e^{ik\phi}/\sqrt{2\pi}, \space k\subseteq\Bbb{Z}\tag{1}$

But the general solution is:$$\psi(\phi)=c_1e^{ik\phi}+c_2e^{-ik\phi}\tag{2}$$

I am unable to derive eq(1) from eq(2) using:

Normalization: $\int_0^{2\pi}|\psi|^2d\phi=1$ $\space$and Cyclic boundary condition :$\psi(\phi)=\psi(\phi+2\pi)$.

Can anyone guide me with the math?

Edit:
I think that in [Full solution of the quantum particle on a ring](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/250232/279008), OP asks why is $c_-$ is taken as zero. As far as I know we can't take any constant to be zero. I am looking to derive eq(1) systematically, only from the two conditions stated. I think that by solving the integrals, we will eventually get $c_1=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and $c_2=0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Full solution of the quantum particle on a ring](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/250232/)

Comment: I don't think so. If I am not wrong, the question was about why we set one of the constants as zero to solve. But I am not looking to solve it in that way. I want to solve it completely using the two conditions stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general solution to the equation
$$\frac{d^2 \psi}{d\phi^2} = -\lambda \psi,\qquad \lambda >0$$

is $\psi(\phi) = c_1 e^{i\sqrt{\lambda}\phi} + c_2 e^{-i\sqrt{\lambda}\phi}$, with $c_1$ and $c_2$ arbitrary.  Imposing periodic boundary conditions on $\phi \in [0,2\pi]$ yields the condition that $\sqrt{\lambda} \equiv \sqrt{\frac{2IE}{\hbar^2}}\in \mathbb Z_+$, but places no restrictions on $c_1$ or $c_2$.  As a result, the Hamiltonian is two-fold degenerate at each energy (except $E=0$), which we should expect from the symmetry of the problem.

This degeneracy can be broken by finding another operator with which the Hamiltonian commutes; the obvious choice is the (angular) momentum operator $P = -i\hbar \frac{d}{d\phi}$.  The eigenstates of this operator are of the form $\psi = c e^{ik\phi}$, where $k$ is now any integer (positive, negative, or zero).

These angular momentum eigenstates are **also** energy eigenstates.  Therefore, the set of functions

$$\psi_k(\phi) = \frac{e^{ik\phi}}{\sqrt{2\pi}},\qquad k\in \mathbb Z$$

is an orthonormal basis for $L^2(S^1)$ consisting of simultaneous eigenstates of $H$ and $P$, with eigenvalues $\frac{\hbar^2 k^2}{2m}$ and $\hbar k$ respectively.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain? This is the most straightforward and clarifying answer :/

Comment: This is the correct answer (and possibly the only correct answer here). There is no notion of "setting $c_0$ for zero" in this case - you simply choose another commuting observable to break the degeneracy, as J. Murray has explained very well.

Answer (score 2):

The solutions of the Schrödinger equation
$${d^2\phi\over d\phi^2}=-k^2\psi$$
where ${2IE\over\hbar^2}$ has been replaced by $k^2$ for convenience, are
$$\psi_k(\phi)=A_ke^{ik\phi}+B_ke^{-ik\phi}\label{1}$$
This is the general solution of Schrödinger equation if $k^2$ is fixed. One could also say that Schrödinger equation admits two solutions: $A_ke^{ik\phi}$ and $B_ke^{-ik\phi}$ if $k\ne 0$.

In Quantum Mechanics, one is interested in all solutions (the set of stationary states). Because of the fact that $\phi$ is an angle, and therefore $\psi(\phi+2\pi)=\psi(\phi)$, any integer value of $k$ leads to a different solution. The general solution is
$$\psi(\phi)=A_0+\sum_{k>0}\big[A_ke^{ik\phi}+B_ke^{-ik\phi}\big]$$
The sum extends over positive values of $k$ because taking into account negative values would be equivalent to exchange $A_k$ and $B_k$ and would result into a double counting of the same solution. The general solution could also be written under the equivalent form
$$\psi(\phi)=A_0+\sum_{k\ne 0} C_ke^{ik\phi}$$
where $C_k=A_k$ if $k>0$ and $C_k=B_{-k}$ if $k<0$. Under this form, the general solution appears as a linear combination of the solutions $C_ke^{ik\phi}$.

Comment: It's worth noting that there are two solutions for $k = 0$ as well:  $\psi = A_0 + B_0 \phi$.  However, the boundary condition $\psi(0) = \psi(2 \pi)$ means that we must have $B_0 = 0$.

Comment: Because of the constrain $\psi(\phi)=\psi(\phi+2\pi)$, the constant $B_0$ should vanish.

Comment: When you say that the sum extends over positive values of $k$ because negative values result in the same solution you're making an implicit assumption that $A_k = A_{-k}$ (and the same for $B_k$), and also that $A_k=B_{-k}$. Without these assumptions you cannot claim that $\psi_k (\phi)$ and $\psi_{-k} (\phi)$ are the same state, can you?